# Merging returned results from two querys for log type feature

Tags: php, mysql, multidimensional-array, pdo

**Information**

I am currently making a history/log page that will show the users payment history with my website.

The two tables are `tasks` and `payouts`

`tasks` is a table full of tasks a user can complete and earn money.
The columns returned that I use are `tasks.title`, `tasks.payment` and `tasks.timestamp`

`payouts` is a table that saves information when a user pays out their earnings.
The columns returned that I use are `payouts.processor`, `payouts.amount` and `payouts.timestamp`

**Problem**

I need to run both query's, merge them ( maybe with a type field so I can easily display them differently when I use a foreach on output ) and then order by timestamp DESC.

**Attempt**

My only attempt has been fruitless, All I did was run both the querys and then use `array_push` which didnt add anything to the end of the array.

**Question**

What would be the best way to have two querys results merged while adding a field called `LOG_TYPE` so when outputting I can do something like this

```
foreach($data as $row){
    if($row['LOG_TYPE'] == 1){
        // Display Payout
    }    else    {
        // Display Task
    }
}
```

**Conclusion**

Any questions will be answered ASAP and any edits will be displayed below. Thank you.

**EDIT**

As requested, here are the two querys I am using.

```
    $STH = $this->database->prepare('SELECT * FROM tasks WHERE completed_by = :userid  ORDER BY timestamp DESC');
    $STH->execute(array(':userid' => $user));
    $data = $STH->fetchAll();

    $STH = $this->database->prepare('SELECT * FROM payouts WHERE user = :userid ');
    $STH->execute(array(':userid' => $user));
    $payouts = $STH->fetchAll();
```

Comment: Share your MySQL queries.  My guess, put the `UNION` command between the queries to allow your MySQL DB do the work

Comment: @AgRizzo Edited main question. thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As AgRizzo commented, try a simple UNION https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html

When running a UNION, your first query sets the names of the fields, and you can add additional strings. So, a psuedo-example:

```
SELECT "1" AS `log_type`, tasks.title, tasks.payment, tasks.timestamp
FROM tasks
WHERE tasks.user_id = 12
UNION
SELECT "2", payouts.processor, payouts.amount , payouts.timestamp
FROM payouts
WHERE payouts.user_id = 12
ORDER BY 4
```

Comment: This works perfectly! Thank you! Also, thank you for explaining UNION aswell.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use the *.  Basically you want this, which will give you 4 columns (log_type, field1, field2, timestamp):

```
SELECT 1 as log_type, tasks.title as field1 , tasks.payment AS field2, tasks.timestamp
FROM tasks
WHERE completed_by = 'foo'
UNION
SELECT 2, payouts.processor, payouts.amouny, payouts.timestamp
FROM payouts
WHERE user = 'bar'
ORDER BY timestamp DESC';
```

Try this

```
$STH = $this->database->prepare('SELECT 1 as log_type, tasks.title as field1 , tasks.payment AS field2, tasks.timestamp
                                 FROM tasks
                                 WHERE completed_by = :userid
                                 UNION
                                 SELECT 2, payouts.processor, payouts.amount and payouts.timestamp
                                 FROM payouts
                                 WHERE user = :userid
                                 ORDER BY timestamp DESC');
$STH->execute(array(':userid' => $user));
$payouts = $STH->fetchAll();
```

Comment: This looks promising, but it doesn't add the LOG_TYPE field?